# Laravel with JetStream and LiveWire not rendering (Tailwind)

Tags: laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I started a new project in Laravel 8 with Jetstream and LiveWire.

It seems everything ok, but I'm not able to show correctly the auth pages.

I created a new laravel project.
I installed the jetstream package with LiveWire
https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html

This is the result of login page:

[image]

The css is not working.

Comment: did you compile the assets? npm install && npm run dev?

Comment: Yes, I compiled

Answer (score 0):

After days of workaround on this issue, I found the problem.

After  `npm run dev`, the console display the following line:

*You have enabled the JIT engine which is currently in preview.*

Documentation [Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode)

For now I changed `mode: 'JIT'`  to `mode: ''` in file *tailwind.config.js*

The project seems to work.